# Online Event Registration - Guests vs. Members

Tags: civievent, user-account, online-registration

Our live CIVICRM environment is CiviCRM 5.67.1, Joomla 4.4.2, PHP 8.1, hosted on Siteground.

Looking for ideas on how to handle this. Currently, we have events in CIVIEVENT that the public and/or members can register for.  They do so by going to a Upcoming Events page, click on the event, and fill out the online registration page.  The Duplicate Matching Rule on all events is Unsupervised.

What I am looking to do is to continue to allow the public/guests (non-members) to continue as-is:  Go to the Upcoming Events page, find the event, and fill out the online registration page.
However, for members (who have an account on the system), I want to enforce the login into the system before they register for an event.  In other words, if they login, great - they go to the Upcoming Events page, find the event, and find that most of their online registration fields are already populated from their account.  If members do not login, however, they are directed to sign into their account before proceeding with registering for an event.
It seems like the Duplicate Matching Rule ought to play a part here, but I am not sure about that.  I would love to hear your ideas about how to solve and execute this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We have provided text messages on every event info and registration form for anonymous users to log in if they already have an account.

Also in some cases, we have checked for email addresses just before visiting the registration page. If the account exists for the email we have redirected the user to login page else to redirection page(This is via custom extension)

Answer (score 1):

We trigger a modal popup, which opens some seconds after the users click on the event registration-button, asking them to login, if they alredy have an account, in order to shorten the process. The login-mask in the popup also holds links for forgotten usernames and passwords.

This helps a lot, we only have around 1-2% of users which have an account and "create" a new one through event registrations.

*** EDIT ***
Forgot to mention: this is a custom coded solution.

Comment: I like that solution.  Is your solution anything that you can share?